# Can an onlick attribute give a function to document.getelementbyID and not replace the last value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a numeric keypad in html that has the numbers 1-9 and don't know if javascript can take an onclick function for each key to display the number in the display div. What's the best approach for what I've got?

```
<div id="display"></div>
<script>
   function  keyvalue (val)
   {
    if (val == 7) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "7";
    } else if (val == 8) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "8"; 
    ....if statements just replace the content.
</script>
<div id="keypad">
       <div id="seven" onClick="keyvalue(7)" class="key"><p>7</p></div>
       <div id="eight" onClick="keyvalue(8)" class="key"><p>8</p></div>
       <div id="nine"  onClick="keyvalue(9)" class="key"><p>9</p></div>
       <div id="four" onClick="keyvalue(4)" class="key"><p>4</p></div>
       <div id="five" onClick="keyvalue(5)" class="key"><p>5</p></div>
       <div id="six" onClick="keyvalue(6)" class="key"><p>6</p></div>
       <div id="one" onClick="keyvalue(1)" class="key"><p>1</p></div>
       <div id="two" onClick="keyvalue(2)" class="key"><p>2</p></div>
       <div id="three" onClick="keyvalue(3)"class="key"><p>3</p></div>
       <div id="zero" onClick="keyvalue(0)"class="zero">0</div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Why not just `function keyvalue (val){ document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = val; }` or `String(val)` if you're against automatic type coercion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for but this works for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/7d44503j/2/

```
<div id="display"></div>
<script>
function keyvalue(val){
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = val;
}
</script>
<div id="keypad">
   <div id="seven" onClick="keyvalue(7)" class="key"><p>7</p></div>
   <div id="eight" onClick="keyvalue(8)" class="key"><p>8</p></div>
   <div id="nine"  onClick="keyvalue(9)" class="key"><p>9</p></div>
   <div id="four" onClick="keyvalue(4)" class="key"><p>4</p></div>
   <div id="five" onClick="keyvalue(5)" class="key"><p>5</p></div>
   <div id="six" onClick="keyvalue(6)" class="key"><p>6</p></div>
   <div id="one" onClick="keyvalue(1)" class="key"><p>1</p></div>
   <div id="two" onClick="keyvalue(2)" class="key"><p>2</p></div>
   <div id="three" onClick="keyvalue(3)" class="key"><p>3</p></div>
   <div id="zero" onClick="keyvalue(0)" class="zero"><p>0</p></div>
</div>
```

Edit: if your original code wasn't working, perhaps it could be due to missing spaces between attributes in the last couple divs as specified in the [HTML syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags).

> Attributes must be separated from each other by one or more space characters.

You can also bind all the handlers at once (instead of through HTML):

```
Array.apply([], document.querySelectorAll('.key')).forEach(function(e) {
  e.onclick = keyvalue.bind(null, e.innerText);
});
```

Or with jQuery:

```
$('.key').click(function() {
  $('#display').text($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Very close. When the buttons click it adds to the display of what numbers your clicking so collecting them not swapping them out.

Comment: in that case use `+=` instead of `=` after `innerHTML`

Comment: That's it! Didn't know what += can do. Thanks a lot arcyqwerty! Case closed

Answer (score 0):

you can pass this to onclick

```
<p id="demo" onClick="myFunction(this, 'red')">Click me to change my text color.</p>
```

Your function may look like:

```
function myFunction(elmnt,clr) {
    elmnt.style.color = clr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most concise solution would actually be to *not* set an event listener on each button, but on the parent element of those buttons, like this:

```
document.getElementById("keypad").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = 
      +document.getElementById("demo").textContent + +event.target.textContent
}, true)
```

The "click" event will pass through the *keypad* container when fired at the keys, so it will be captured there, no matter which key is the target.

Answer (score -2):

it is onclick not onClick in javascript , that is the issue

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6fm0j8uq/4/

```
<div id="display"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="keypad">
       <div id="seven" onclick="keyvalue(7)" class="key"><p>7</p></div>
       <div id="eight" onclick="keyvalue(8)" class="key"><p>8</p></div>
       <div id="nine"  onclick="keyvalue(9)" class="key"><p>9</p></div>
   </div> 

<script>
   function  keyvalue (val)
   {
    console.log('val clicked is '+val);
    if (val == 7) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "7";
    }else if(val == 8){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "8";
    }
   }

</script>
```

Comment: except he's using the HTML attribute, which is case-insensitive

Comment: @Touffy: please check my code it is working u cannot make it -1 . please

Comment: I don't care if your code works. The explanation you give is misleading.

Comment: What you say is correct but not relevant, as the `onclick` property is not used anywhere in the code, only the HTML `onclick` attribute which is not case sensetive.

Comment: @Touffy you  can try with onClick , it will not work ... this is for the viewers who can learn some thing from here ... you cannot make it -1 for  any stupid issue.

Comment: @Shelly It *will* work, regardless of whether you use `onClick` or `onclick` or `oNcLiCk` or `ONCLICK` http://jsfiddle.net/6fm0j8uq/5/